# Асинхронность Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Есть модели и несколько записей в них:

```
  Personage({
    id: 1,
    note_id: 3,
    name: "neme",
    number: 4
  }, {
    id: 2,
    note_id: 1,
    name: "neme",
    number: 5
  }, {
    id: 3,
    note_id: 2,
    name: "neme",
    number: 3
  });
Note({
  id: 1,
  body: "first-text1",
  text: "text3"
}, {
  id: 2,
  body: "first-text2",
  text: "text2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  body: "first-text3",
  text: "text3"
});
```

Как имея значение поля `text` модели `Note` (например, `text3`) получить все объекты модели `Personage`, у которых свойство `note_id` совпадает с `id` записи модели `Note`? Пробовал так:

```
  Note.find({
    text: "text3"
  }, function(err, note) {
    console.log("start");
    for (var i = 0; i < note.length; i++) {
      console.log("1");
      Personage.find(function(err, personage) {
        console.log("2");
        for (var j = 0; j < personage.length; j++)
          console.log("3");
        if (note[i].id === personage[j].note_id) {
          console.log("end");
          console.log(personage[j]);
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

Выводит: `start,1,1,1,2,3,3,3`
`end` так и не выводится. 
Как быть?

Comment: если `end` не выводится, значит условие `note[i].id === personage[j].note_id` не выполняется.

Comment: @Grundy не угадал, тут проблема в том что `"3" === 3` => `false`

Comment: @Darth, `note[i].id` - число, `personage[j].note_id` - число, судя по объекту выше - так что никаких проблем с типами

Comment: Пока идет запрос к базе то цикл проходит все итерации. Во втором цикле i уже больше note.length

Comment: @MarkFarin, вот [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486204/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-javascript) наверно лучше смотреть. Прям ваша ситуация

Comment: @Grundy Голова кипит, как это все склеить.?

Comment: там же конкретное решение с циклом

Comment: Там без nodejs и mongodb

Comment: @MarkFarin, не имеет значения, все то же самое

Comment: Как можно это реализовать здесь? Не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < note.length; i++) {
  console.log("1");
  (function(index){
    Personage.find(function(err, personage) {
      console.log("2");
      for (var j = 0; j < personage.length; j++)
        console.log("3");
      if (note[index].id === personage[j].note_id) {
        console.log("end");
        console.log(personage[j]);
      }
    })
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: два дня искал решение. Благодарю за помощь. Очень помог.