# Использование promise с циклом for

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность, promise

Задача: собираю данные геодаты с сервера (не моего). Для этого формирую запрос для определенного промежутка координат и в цикле for отправляю запрос на сервер. Ответ записываю в файл и дабы сервер не банил меняю ip адрес через tor-control. Ожидание ответа реализовано с использованием promise. Это в идеале. На деле (судя по логам в консоли) данные отправляются как попало. Подскажите где я повернул не туда.

```
for (var i = xMin; i <= xMax; i++) {
    for (var k = yMin; k <= yMax; k++) {
        var swp = swPoint(k, i);
        var nep = nePoint(k, i);
        var llsw = pointToLatLong(swp[0], swp[1]);
        var llne = pointToLatLong(nep[0], nep[1]);
        var datatosend = 'fromlat=' + llsw[0].toString() + 'tolat=' + llne[0].toString() + 'fromlng=' + llsw[1].toString() + 'tolng' + llne[1].toString();

        currX = k;
        currY = i;

        filename = "json/" + currX.toString() + "_" + currY.toString() + "_" + zoom.toString() + ".json";

        options.body = datatosend;

        console.log(filename);

        GetData(options)
        .then(body =>{
            return WriteToFile(body, filename);
        })
        .then(() =>{
            return GetNewCircuit();
        })
        .then(() =>{
            console.log('Step finished');
        })
    }
}
```

Судя по логам получается что он 4 раза проносится по циклу не дожидаясь выполнения предыдущих операций.

Текст лога консоли:

```
json/0_0_1.json
json/1_0_1.json
json/0_1_1.json
json/1_1_1.json
Get response
json/1_1_1.json
Circuit changed
Step finished
Get response
json/1_1_1.json
Circuit changed
Step finished
Get response
json/1_1_1.json
Circuit changed
Step finished
Get response
json/1_1_1.json
Circuit changed
Step finished
```

Вызываемые методы:

```
function GetNewCircuit(){
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject){
        new_identity('127.0.0.1', 9051, cookie, function(err){
            if(!err){
               console.log('Circuit changed');
               resolve()
            } else{
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}

function GetData(reqOptions){
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject){
        request(reqOptions, function(error,response,body){
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                console.log('Get response');
                resolve(body);
            }
            else{
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

function WriteToFile(dataToWrite, fileToWrite){
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.writeFile(fileToWrite, dataToWrite, function(err) {
           if(!err){
               console.log(fileToWrite);
               resolve();
           }
           else{
               reject(err);
           }
        }); 
    });
}
```

С js'ом знакомство только начинаю, поэтому если кроме ответа еще и посоветуете где и как лучше ознакамливаться буду только рад.

Comment: я может что-то мимо смотрю, но вроде как ясно, что цикл циклом, а запрос на сервер внутри него выполняется, и выполняются запросы асинхронно, то есть запрос ушел и не дожидаясь ответа цикл погнал дальше.
Даже не знаю как здесь запихать можно, через замыкание наверное вариант есть и при каждом успешном запросе флаг увеличивать на единицу и при новом запуске проверять не привышен ли флаг и если превышен то выходить из функции...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В коде этом сразу две основных проблемы (из трех) начинающих javascript-разработчиков вижу я.

**Проблема один - непонимание асинхронности.**
Разумеется, цикл не ждет возврата результата асинхронной операции, чтобы прокрутиться дальше.

Представьте что у вас четыре гиперактивных двортерьера, и вы подряд кидаете им четыре мячика. В каком порядке они их принесут обратно? Да черт его знает.

А то что внутри Promise.then, это колбек, только написанный удобнее.

**Что делать?**
**Не надо:**
Первое решение которое приходит в голову, а давайте дождемся конца первой операции, а потом уже счетчик цикла увеличим и в следующей итерации запустим следующую операцию. Но этим Вы просто превращаете асинхронную операцию в синхронную и теряете весь профит от асинхронности.
**Надо:**
Понять что основная проблема этого кода не в асинхронности, а в том что Вы не понимаете замыкания. Ну то есть вас не смущает что у вас консольложится `json/1_1_1.json` столько раз?

**Проблема два:**
непонимание областей видимости в js, они же замыкания. Вопрос про потерю значения переменной в цикле - топ 1 вопрос на собеседованиях на мидл разработчика, при неответе на который разговор можно сворачивать. На этом ресурсе этот вопрос в разных формулировках встречается пару раз в неделю. Например [вот здесь на него подробно ответили](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486204/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-javascript) (не упоминая block scope в es6 правда).

Ну то есть ядро ошибки в вашем коде выглядит как-то так:

```
for(var i = 0; i<4; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, 1000)
}
```

`setTimeout` тут - как пример простейшей асинхронной операции. Если Вы не понимаете почему тут выведет 4 раза 4 - надо медитировать пока не поймете.     Обязательно.
Если вкратце, то это происходит потому что скоуп в js для var переменных - это функция, а не фигурные скобочки. Цикл отдельного скоупа не образует и все четыре раза функция будет ссылаться на одну и ту же переменную i, на одну и ту же область памяти.

**Ок, я все понял, все равно хочу синхронно.**
Для того чтобы хитро управлять ходом управления множества асинхронных запросов есть ряд распространенных библиотек, например [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/), посмотрите например на `async.waterfall`

Comment: Развернутый ответ. Большое спасибо, понимания действительно прибавилось (особенно насчет скоупов), после разработки сингловых игр сложно переключиться на web да еще и на другой язык. Единственно что хотел спросить, а если мне ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО необходима синхронность? Я понимаю что это уже не к node'js тогда, его фишка асинхронность, но что бы вы посоветовали? У меня после каждого успешного запроса необходимо производить смену ip дабы возвращались нормальные данные а не массив с текстом 'spam'. В случае же асинхронности мне могут вернуться 4 запроса в раз. Как мне тогда быть?

Comment: @justyx, я фронт а не нодист, поэтому на сто процентов не уверен как там это сейчас это принято делать, но кажется с помощью этой либы: http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: @justyx `last_request = last_request.then(() => GetData())` и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Собери промисы в массив в цикле потом дождись их выполнения используя Promise.all

Comment: тогда итерации останутся независимыми и их порядок выполнения будет не гарантирован

Comment: @Grundy из вопроса я не понял, что порядок резолвинга промисов важен. Если важен, можно использовать, Promise.mapSeries (из bluebird), https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-series или альтернативу из библиотеки, которая используется. Базовая техника остается той же, меняется только метод