# nodejs/request.Порядок вывода данных

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api

Вывожу диалоги из vk (messages.getDialogs) через request.

- Первый запрос получает список диалогов.
- В коллбэке первого запроса цикл запросов на информацию о каждом пользователе из результатов.

Но выводятся они не по порядку, а вразнобой. Например, человек, с которым общался неделю назад, стал на первое место, а должен быть десятым.

Я так понимаю это из-за асинхронности? Как можно исправить?

```
request({
    url: url,
    json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
    body.response.map(function(data) {
      request({url:"https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids="+data.uid+"&fields=photo_50", json:true}, function(err, res, body) {
        body.response.map(function(data2){
          $("#dialogs").append('<div id="'+data2.uid+'" class="dialog"><div class="photo"><img src="'+data2.photo_50+'"></div><div class="mess"><div class="name">'+data2.first_name+' '+data2.last_name+'</div><div class="message">'+data.body+'</div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
        });
       });
    })
})
```

Comment: API нормально отдает данные. Я через браузер проверял.

Comment: Посмотрите код. Может это из-за двух запросов сразу?

Comment: Очень даже возможно. Изолируйте проблему. Не смотрите на наблюдаемые результаты, смотрите на данные внутри. Отладчиком, console.log'ом, чем угодно. Скажем, попробуйте вывести `data` и `data2` прямо перед `append`'ом.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую.
Мне там в json выводится первое значение ненужное - цифры. Как это можно убрать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555732/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-promise-%D1%81-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-for/555744#555744