# Нахождение ближайшей точки Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps-api

Подскажите:
у меня есть 8 точек на карте я хочу найти ближайшую точку от нажатия мыши. 
Вот код.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++)
    {

        var request = {
            origin: point1,
            destination: Markers[i],
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                distance = parseInt(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
                console.log('in' + distance);
                if (distance < maxD) {
                    maxD = distance;
                    pointSave = Markers[i];             
                }
            }
        });
    }
    calcRoute(point1, pointSave);
```

в переменную Point1 автоматически добавляется координаты клика мыши. 
В Markers массив точек до которых надо построить маршрут.
функция CalcRoute строит маршрут.

Ошибки:

1) Почему в блоке кода

```
` directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                distance = parseInt(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
                console.log('in' + distance);
                if (distance < maxD) {
                    maxD = distance;
                    pointSave = Markers[i];             
                }
            }
        });`
```

Точка Marker[i] не видна? вообще не хочет сохранятся . 
И переменная i там почему-то всегда равна максимальному размеру массива.

2) Так же переменная distance является глобальной. Почему она не сохраняет свое значение после блока  directionsService.route

Comment: При чем тут C#? (в метке)

Answer (score 1):

Корень данных проблем кроется в асинхронности вызова замыкания, которое является параметром `directionsService.route`.

1. Это замыкание будет вызвано **после** выхода из цикла. Соответственно `i` будет иметь значение `Markers.length`, а `Markers[Markers.length]` не существует.
2. `distance` хоть и является глобальной, но получает значения позже чем вызывается `calcRoute()`, поэтому вы не видите нужного результата.

См. также ответы на вопросы:

[Использование promise с циклом for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555732)

[Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290)