# Не работающие события js

Tags: javascript

Есть список(11 элементов)

```
<ul class="styled-list">
 <li class="styled-list-item">1</li>
 <li class="styled-list-item">1</li>
 <li class="styled-list-item">1</li>
 <li class="styled-list-item">1</li>
</ul>
```

Есть набор абзацев, каждый из которых соответствует элементу списка:

```
<p class="lesson-info-box"><p> 
<p class="lesson-info-box"><p> 
<p class="lesson-info-box"><p> 
<p class="lesson-info-box"><p>
```

У каждого абзаца через css прописана прозрачность и абсолютное позиционирование, хочу сделать так чтобы при клике на первый элемент списка, прозрачность у первого абзаца пропадала, он становился видимым, при клике на второй элемент списка тоже самое происходило бы со вторым абзацем.
Вот как я пытался решить проблему:

```
var itemList = document.querySelectorAll('.styled-list .styled-list-item');
var detailsList = document.querySelectorAll('.lesson-info-box');
for(i=0;i<itemList.length;i++){
  itemList[i].onclick = function(){
          detailsList[i].className = "lesson-info-box onclick-list-item";
          }
    };
```

Беру два массива, первый это все элементы списка на странице, второй абзацы. Потом в цикле перебираю каждый элементы и вешаю на него обработчик. Не понимаю, но это не работает... В отладчике четко видно, что при клике на первый элемент, в i подставляется значение 11. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: [Принцип работы вложенных функций или “непонятное замыкание” в JavaScript](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486219/191482)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо, я видел эту тему, недавно начал с js знакомиться, сразу не понял что это решение моей проблемы, попробую)

Comment: измените обработчик `onclick` на `function(i){detailsList[i].className = "lesson-info-box onclick-list-item";}.bind(i)`. Проблема в том, что к каждой функции привязно не конкретное значение переменной `i`, но сама переменная. И когда обработчик вызывается, он ищет переменную `i` и т.к. цикл уже был звершен находит эту переменную со значением 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно будет не навешивать на каждый элемент списка обработчик, а использовать делегирование событий - это первый момент.  Если не знаете что это такое, то  вкратце это подход, когда событие вешается не на каждый элемент, а на его "контейнер" и уже в обработчике идет проверка на каком элементе возникло событие и выполнение необходимых действий. 
Что необходимо знать для решения задачи:
1. элемент на котором произошло событие.
2. его индекс в массиве.
Итак, с первым пунктом все просто, проверим `event.target`, для второго пункта можно воспользоваться методом `forEach`.
Напомню, индекс элемента нам необходим для доступа к нужному элементу в массиве с описаниями.
Так же понадобиться функция показывающая необходимый элемент.
Затем собрав все в кучу получиться следующий код:

```js
// Итак получим все еобходимые нам узлы DOM, элементы списка и описания к ним сразу поместим в массив. Это понадобиться для работы с методом forEach
var container = document.querySelector('.container dl');
var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.apply(container.querySelectorAll('dt'));
var details = Array.prototype.slice.apply(container.querySelectorAll('dd'));
// функция показа элемента, ее будем вызывать позже.
function showDetails(arr, i) {
  arr[i].style.opacity = 1;
}
// вешаем обработчик на контейнер
container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // это привычка :) отменяет действия браузера по умолчанию (полезно для обработки кликов по ссылкам..)
  if (event.target.tagName == 'DT') { // проверяем что событие возникло на элементе списка
    for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) { // просто проходим по массиву с описаниями и сбрасываем прозрачность. Необходимо для скрытия уже показанного описания при клике по другому элементу списка
      details[i].style.opacity = '';
    }
    //Дальше на массиве с элементами списка запускаем forEach
    listItems.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
      if (item == event.target) { // сравниваем каждый элемент массива с элементом события
        showDetails(details, i); // запускаем функцию показа описания
      }
    });
  }
}, false);
```

```css
dd {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <dl>
    <dt>элемент списка</dt>
    <dd>а это наверное описание термина или пункта списка</dd>
    <dt>элемент списка</dt>
    <dd>а это наверное описание термина или пункта списка</dd>
    <dt>элемент списка</dt>
    <dd>а это наверное описание термина или пункта списка</dd>
    <dt>элемент списка</dt>
    <dd>а это наверное описание термина или пункта списка</dd>
    <dt>элемент списка</dt>
    <dd>а это наверное описание термина или пункта списка</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

P.S. Можно воспользоваться и обычным циклом `for`, но тогда необходимо сохранить текущий `i` в замыкании.Для этого можно воспользоваться функциональным выражением с немедленно вызываемой функцией в теле цикла. Выглядит это так:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
        if(listItems[i] == event.target) {
            showDetails(details, i);
        }
    })(i);
}
```

**[Дополнение]**
Как правильно заметил [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) бегать в цикле каждый раз по элементам может быть накладно, если допустим у нас их несколько тысяч...
Поэтому непосредственно к разметке в ответе можно применить вместо цикла следующее:
Так как описание элемента списка идет сразу же за самим элементом, можно получить элемент в дереве DOM, стоящий справа от того покоторому кликнули и произвести над ним манипуляции.

```
if(event.target.nextElementSibling.tagName == 'DD') {
    event.target.nextElementSibling.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное) буду разбираться.

Comment: @Alexey Vladimirovich, Да не за что. Замыкания в JS  - это мощный инструмент, овладев которым разрабатывать станет легче и интереснее.    
Так же хочу обратить внимание на события и способы их навешивания. Крайне не рекомендую использовать `on{событие}` - этот подход не является гибким и устарел.

Comment: что-то пример с делегированием совсем печальный, каждый раз бежать в цикле по всем элементам чтобы определить по какому щелкнули?

Comment: @Grundy, Я не прфи JS сам еще учусь, поэтому не знаю как еще получить индекс нужного элемента в массиве. Если же отказаться от массивов,  то именно в данной разметке можно использовать навигацию по DOM, а именно выполнять действия над правым соседом... Хотя кому я все это рассказываю.... Как бы сделали Вы?

Comment: @pepel_xD, можно например в дата атрибут запихать индекс, и брать его у таргета

Comment: @Grundy, на мой взгляд дата атрибут, самый оптимальный вариант, тогда будет более гибкий код, без привязки к классам, тегам, разметке... А если данное реализовывать как компонент в стиле ООП, какой вариант сброса прозрачности будет более правильный: в цикле по всем элементам (как сейчас), либо генерить свое событие, которое допустим будет запоминать текущий показываемый элемент в переменную, а затем обращаться к ней и сбрасывать прозрачность?