# Замыкание с использованием Named Function Expression

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Здравствуйте, изучаю JS,пытаюсь разобраться в решении задачи на замыкание:

```
function makeArmy() {

  var shooters = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var shooter = function me() {    //*
      alert( me.i );
    };
    shooter.i = i;                  //**

    shooters.push(shooter);
  }

  return shooters;
}

var army = makeArmy();

army[0](); // 0
army[1](); // 1
```

Насколько я понимаю shooter ссылается на одну и ту же функцию(объект).Но при при использовании NFE разные i.

Вопрос: почему i не перезаписывается?

Упростил для себя:

```
 b = {};
    d = [];
    a = с= b;
    a.i=1;
    d.push(a);
    c.i=2;
    d.push(c);
```

---

> на каждой итерации цикла FOR будит создаваться переменная shooter
>           с присвоением свойств объекта в значении Function  "  var 
>          shooter = function me() { ...} "

Я думаю,что здесь Вы не правы,объявление сработает один раз.(https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics)

Насколько я понял дело даже не в замыкании,а просто в использовании функции как объекта.И так как Function Expression создаются в процессе выполнения выражения,это будут разные объекты,соответственно поэтому i и не перезаписывается,а NFE для того чтобы обратиться к свойству.

**Однако непонятно еще вот что,если написать как Function Declaration,все равно получается разные объекты,но ведь** https://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression

> Основное отличие между ними: функции, объявленные как Function
>   Declaration, создаются интерпретатором до выполнения кода.

```
function makeArmy() {

  var shooters = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    function shooter() {    
      //alert( me.i );     //убрал для примера
    };
    shooter.i = i;                  

    shooters.push(shooter);
  }
  console.log(shooters);  //добавил для примера
  return shooters;
}

var army = makeArmy();

army[0](); // 0
army[1](); // 1
```

Comment: сейчас позову дубликатора, подождите

Comment: Если Вы уверены,что кто-то задавал подобный вопрос,поделитесь ссылкой,а так Ваш комментарий бесполезен.

Comment: Спит дубликатор  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну может он проснется и заметит,что хоть задача тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486204/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-javascript/486224 такая же,вопросы другие.

Comment: упрощенный код не соответствует исходному. должно было так:
`d = [];
    a = {};
    a.i=1;
    d.push(a);
    a = {};
    a.i = 2;
    d.push(a);`

Comment: Да я уже понял,ниже добавил развернутый ответ

Comment: Я не понял, если честно, вопрос. Почему i должна перезаписываться? Во что она должна перезаписываться?

Comment: Вопрос уже про  Function Declaration ниже жирным выделил.А так да,изначально был вопрос почему значение i перезаписывается.

Comment: @Александр простите, но я не вижу ни единого слова в вопросе, которое было бы выделено жирным.

Comment: @Александр а, вы, видимо, про ответ говорили ваш.

Comment: @smellyshovel Да,про Function Declaration в цикле.

Comment: @Александр, [block-level function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics)

Answer (score 1):

**_ почему i не перезаписывается _**

```
function makeArmy() {
    var shooters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
/*
    *   на каждой итерации цикла FOR будит создаваться переменная shooter
        с присвоением свойств объекта в значении Function  "  var 
       shooter = function me() { ...} "     
*/
/*
       Объявления Function Expression с присвоением обеления Function
        Declaration внутри цикла FOR. Такой подход никакой функциональной
        нагрузки для тела декларативной функции makeArmy не несет
*   !   в  теле функции makeArmy " me " не несёт не какого значения, его
        просто НЕТ !!!
*/
    var shooter = function me(){
/*
    *   тело функции содержит метод  алёрт, в нутрии которого происходит
       обращение к  значению свойства ключа i объекта именованным "me"
*/  
        alert( me.i );
    }
/*
    *   *   свойству обекта(функции),, в ключе i  присваиваем значения
            переменой i, объявленной циклом FOR "  shooter.i = i " 
*/  
    shooter.i = i;
/*
    *   *   *   в массив методом push , итым элементом добавляем аргумент
                содержащий результат переменой shooter
*/          
     shooters.push(shooter);

  }
/*  
    *   возвращаем массив методов(функций)
*/
  return shooters;
}
/*
    *   присваиваем переменой army результат работы метода(функции) makeArmy
 */
var army = makeArmy(); 

/*
    *   открываем  в консоли массив army
    *   видим что он наполнен 10-ю функциями
    *   *   и каждая имеет ключ "i"  с расширением №
*/

console.dir(
    army
)
army[0](); // 0
army[1](); // 1
```

**_____ про замыкание _____**

```
function makeArmy_1(_perem) {
    var perem = "в функцию аргументом _perem передано " + (_perem || "нечего");
    var shooters = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var shooter = function me(){
/*
    *   тело функции содержит метод  алёрт, в нутрии которого происходит
         конкатенация значений 
        1. значения переданного аргументу в функцию  +  2. значению
        свойства ключа i объекта именованным "me" + 3.результат последней
        итерации сохранённой в переменой i
*/  
        alert(_perem +" "+ me.i + " последняя итерация " + i)}
    shooter.i = i;
    shooters.push(shooter)
    } 
/*
    возвращаем анонимную функцию
*/  
  return function(_num){
/*
     *   тело функции содержит ссылку  на локальную переменную
     *  !    возможность обращения к ней и есть замыкание
*/  
        shooters[_num || 0]()
/*
        выводим результат переменой perem в консоль браузера
*/      
        console.log(perem)

    }
}
var army_1 = makeArmy_1(); 
/*
    *   открываем  в консоли массив army
    *   видим одну анонимную функцию 
*/
console.dir(
    army_1
)
army_1(5)
```